# Error 2448: Can't assign a value to this object ... Why not?

Tags: ms-access

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
  Me.Bathroom = Forms!frmBathrooms!ID
  Me.txtBathInfo.Caption = "Bathroom Room Number: " & 
        DLookup("Room", "tblRooms", "ID = " & 
           DLookup("Room", "tblBathrooms", "ID = " & Me.Bathroom))
  Me.RecordSource = "SELECT * FROM tblStalls WHERE Bathroom = " & Me.Bathroom
  Me.Recordset.AddNew
End Sub
```

where Line 2 `Me.Bathroom = Forms!frmBathrooms!ID` is tripping the error. 
Debugger says `Me.Bathroom = 1, Forms!frmBathrooms!ID = 38`. Basically I'm trying to automatically make this form's Bathroom field match that of the frmBathrooms form's ID. "Me" is a form for items in the bathroom; there can be many items.

How the hell is that throwing an error? I can't find anything dispite about an hour of searching around. I understand the message, but not how this could be throwing it?

The Bathroom field of the Item table is in the form's recordsource, etc. Ideas?

Comment: what kind of field is Bathroom in your table?

Comment: It's a Lookup Field (I know they're not great to use, but this really will be a strictly Access DB so I didn't see the harm) containing the Numeric auto-number of tblBathrooms.ID. I actually got this figured out though... Type out this question and wait 4 minutes, it clicked. Will provide answer.

Comment: Okay this forum lack-of-reputation stuff is getting on my nerves now.. just wanted to show the answer as an answer.. For anyone else having the same problem, all I did was literally move lines 2 and 3 down to below Me.Recordset.AddNew (so that it changes source and adds a new record BEFORE changing the Me.Bathroom and caption). If someone else could please write that in an answer, easy 15.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with lookup fields in my opinion. When you open the form and no record is present, you can simply use the form to start a new record (access will create it for you), unless your form is not bound to any recordsource

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone else having the same problem, all I did was literally move lines 2 and 3 down to below Me.Recordset.AddNew (so that it changes source and adds a new record BEFORE changing the Me.Bathroom and caption).  – user1394455

Answer (score 3):

Had the same problem, but it had nought to do with VBA syntax.
I attempted to set a control (ordernumber) on a form.
This ordernumber had to be calculated, which i proceeded to do in VBA.
After calculation I would try to set the control (ordernumber) on the form. And that triggered an 2448 error at runtime.
Subsequently I discovered that in form design, i had set the control source to a calculation already. So run-time VBA would not allow me to set the control as well.
After removal of the calculation in the Control Source of the control in the form design --> Property Sheet window it worked fine.
I admit, really stupid mistake, but there you have it.
Hope this helps
--X--

Answer (score 0):

The main form has to be editable in order to change the drop down list, even in the form header area. (VBA was making it non-editable upon loading.)